# DAX Ranking events year over year

Tags: excel-formula, powerpivot, dax

I have a table of data that has a format similar to the following:

```
EventID | Event Date
--------------------
   1    | 1/1/2014
   2    | 2/8/2014
   3    | 10/1/2014
   4    | 2/5/2014
   5    | 4/1/2014
   6    | 9/1/2014
```

What I am trying to do is create a DAX formula to rank each event in the order that it happened for the year.  So I want to end up with something like this.  This way I can compare the events year over year as the events don't happen on any regular time schedule.

```
Event Date | Year | Rank
------------------------
1/1/2014   | 2014 |  1
2/8/2014   | 2014 |  2
10/1/2014  | 2014 |  3
2/5/2015   | 2015 |  1
4/1/2015   | 2015 |  2
9/1/2015   | 2015 |  3
```

I have tried to do this by creating a formula that will give me the day number of the year:

```
Day of Year =(YEARFRAC(CONCATENATE("Jan 1 ", YEAR([Event Date])),[Event Date])*360)+1
```

Then using rankX on this table, but I cant seem to get the proper result.  Perhaps I am not understanding the use of rankX or going about this the right way.

```
=RANKX(FILTER(Event,EARLIER(Event[Event Year])=Event[Event Year]),Event[Day of Year])
```

or

```
=RANKX(All(Event[Event Year]),[Day of Year],,1,Dense)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following measures:

```
[Year]:=YEAR(LASTDATE(Event[Event Date]))
```

and

```
[Rank]:=RANKX(FILTER(ALL(Event),[Year]=YEAR(MAX(Event[Event Date]))),FIRSTDATE(Event[Event Date]),,1,DENSE)
```

and this is the result that you get:

[image]

*Note: My dates are in UK format and I suspect yours were in US format, so the rankings do not appear to tally with your example, but it does work!*